# Find if the ActiveDocument has any tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to see if the ActiveDocument has any tables.

If any are found then execute some code.
Else execute other code.

How do I find/not find a table in Word?

```vb
Public HasTable As Boolean

Sub xxx()

' Somehow find a table or not find a table and give HasTable True/False based on if found

If HasTable = True
  ' Do code
Else
  ' Do code
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Like @Ike's Answer, just use the [Tables.Count property](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/word.tables.count) of a document.

Answer (score 3):

You can check for the number of tables of the document:

```vb
Public Function hasTables(doc As Word.Document) As Boolean
hasTables = doc.Tables.Count > 0
End Function
```

You can call this function e.g. `IF hasTables(ActiveDocument) then`

I wouldn't store that in a public variable. `ActiveDocument` might change or tables get inserted ...